# python random.sample("abc",3) . how to use regular expressions in place of "abc"

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to generate random number in python using random.sample . This is how I am writing code .

```
import random
r = "".join(random.sample("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 10))
```

Above code generates random numbers of length 10 whose letters are populated from the letters a-z. How can i use regular expressions over there like [a-z]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this instead

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
>>> ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

If you want to generate digits you can use `range`

```
>>> map(str, range(10))
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the pyparsing module handy, you can use the srange method to expand a regex character set to a string of characters:

```
>>> from pyparsing import srange
>>> srange('[a-z]')
u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> srange('[a-z0-9]')
u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
```